# ASP.NET MVC4 - images from database load slow

Tags: database, image, asp.net-mvc-4, load

Hope you can help me to find a solution in one strange for me web-site behaviour created on ASP.NET MVC 4.

At home page of my web site I have about 30 images for categories. They are loaded from MSSQL 2008 database. But the problem is that some of them (every time different images) load very slow.
All images were loaded quite fast but five of them not. Their size is the same as others.

Why?
Can you explain me what's going on and where should I look to a solution? Web site looks bad when those images appear after some seconds

Here is a link to a screen capture of firebug http://i.piccy.info/i7/354e9ca195cc13f412e5e5813d279d97/4-55-323/7677732/Network.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure why the images load slowly, but you might want to consider caching them if they are not likely to change very often, this means it will only be slow when loaded for the first time after the cache has been emptied.

Comment: Not all images but only five images from thirty load slow. I can be wrong but as far as I know browser automatically cashes images with the same links. My links are the same every time and looks like '<img src="/MainPage/ShowSparePartsImage/4" width="75" height="75">'

Answer (score 0):

Storing images directly in a database is not often thought of as best practice.
I suggest experimenting with storing the images as files then storing the paths in a database.

[addendum in response to author's comment]
It may not be a database problem at all. For example, many browsers limit the number of concurrent connections to an individual web server. It may be that the web browser sends, say, 20 requests for images and then once one is complete, the 21st request is made. Thus, some images won't even begin loading until others have completely finished. Per-client limitations may also exist on the web server.

Chrome and IE9 come with decent profilers which show how long different requests take. Firefox similarly has an add-on called Firebug. These tools should help narrow the exact problem.

Comment: Yes, this is possible solution not to store images to database but to disk. Now for me it's important to understand why 25 images are loaded for 50ms and first five of tham load 2-3 seconds. Always first five loads with delay and I can't understand this. Is is issue of my code, shered hosting, database slow responce or ...

Comment: Yes, I used firebug and see that first images load slowly and others are ok. Please see screnn capture here http://i.piccy.info/i7/354e9ca195cc13f412e5e5813d279d97/4-55-323/7677732/Network.jpg